# What's the difference between 'subject + did + verb' and 'subject + simple past'?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between these two setences?

> We did have a meeting, but it was a bit rushed.
>
> We had a meeting, but it was a bit rushed.

Comment: Both are fine, and would often mean exactly the same thing. Including the "helper" verb ***did*** is usually done when either that word or the word ***have*** can be heavily stressed in order to emphatically refute something contextually stated or implied. Your *but it was a bit rushed* clause does provide such a context (rather weakly, admittedly) so it's quite acceptable to include the auxiliary verb. But you don't *have* to - it's essentially a stylistic choice of little or no significance.

Comment: See duplicate.  "We did have a meeting" is used when the person you are talking to expects the opposite.

Comment: @James: But note that OP's exact example would be a perfectly natural response to someone saying/asking *I assume the meeting went ahead as planned, even though it was due to start just half an hour before the World Cup final?* That's to say emphatic ***did** have* can be licensed simply by the ***but*** clause here (audience might have expected an "ordinary" meeting rather than a "rushed" one).

Answer (score 1):

Emphasis.  The first is emphasized.

This is done if:

- there is some doubt it happened, or happens regularly, and the speaker/writer wants to remove that doubt.
- the speaker believes the listener is not listening, understanding something, understanding something is needed.
- the speaker wants to emphasize something is in past tense, especially with verbs that don't change according to tense like *put*, *set*, *cut*, etc.:  E.g. *I did put it away*.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, 'did' would likely be stressed and the sentence would be about that point (ie that a meeting *did* take place).

The second sentence is more neutral. If anything, the second part would be stressed, or neither.